# Linking Error with Static Libraries

Tags: iphone, ios6, static-linking, xcode4.6

I am trying to get some static libraries into my project and I've given the **Header Search Path** under build setting and that is successfully run but when I start to use some more static files then it will give me the following type of error:

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMocrDirectoryDataSource", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in RecognitionViewController.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMocrEngine", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in RecognitionViewController.o

When <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click on the `CMocrDirectoryDataSource` and `CMocrEngine` files then it will redirect me to the following defined file that means linking to the file is fine but why this error may occur..

Please if anyone got the same kind of problem then help me soon..

Kevin

Comment: Is your project ARC enabled?

Comment: @Sudershanshastri What would that even have to do with a linker error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Remove all of your classes from compile sources, then click the + button and search for the term '.m'. Highlight every class, then click add. Build and run again.

Sometimes Xcode misses adding classes in its compile list.